# Xamarin forms push notifications on android replace previous messages

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, pushsharp

I have added on my Xamarin.Forms project the plug-in [Xam.Plugin.PushNotification](https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification) to display notifications and it's working fine.

On my back-end system I have implemented [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) to send notification which is working fine.

The only problem I have is that every notification which I send, always replace the previous one on the mobile phone. If I send for example 4 notifications, only the last one remain displayed on the mobile phone.
Where and how can I set to display all notifications and NOT replace previous ones ?
Is it a parameter on the back-end system while sending the notification (PushSharp) or a parameter in the app plig-in Xam.Plugin.PushNotification ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Nit sure about plugins but in Android there is a parameter in notification manager var mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService); mNotificationManager.Notify(id++, builder.Build());